# How to have a C# TCP Chat Server listen for connections from multiple clients?

Tags: c#, tcp, chat, ipv4

So this is code for my TCP based chat server written in c#. It works no problem for connecting two computers via ipv4 for chat, but I am wanting the server program to listen for and accept, then send a "sucessfully joined" message to the computers that joined.

I am wondering is there a way to change this code to do this?

Server code:

```
IPAddress ipAd = IPAddress.Parse(IPV4.Text); //use local m/c IP address, and use the same in the client

/* Initializes the Listener */
TcpListener myList = new TcpListener(ipAd, 8001);

/* Start Listeneting at the specified port */
myList.Start();

MessageBox.Show("The server is running at port 8001...");
MessageBox.Show("The local End point is  :" + myList.LocalEndpoint);
MessageBox.Show("Looking for other computer");

Socket s = myList.AcceptSocket();
Console.WriteLine("Found buddy " + s.RemoteEndPoint);

ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
s.Send(asen.GetBytes(satt.Text));
MessageBox.Show("The message " + satt.Text + " was sent to the computer with IP address " + IPV4.Text);

byte[] b = new byte[100];
int k = s.Receive(b);
for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
    Console.Write(Convert.ToChar(b[i]));
    
    /* clean up */
    s.Close();
    myList.Stop();
```

Client code:

```
TcpClient tcpclnt = new TcpClient();

tcpclnt.Connect(RecieveIPAdd.Text, 8001); // use the ipaddress as in the server program

MessageBox.Show("Connected");

Stream stm = tcpclnt.GetStream();

MessageBox.Show("Listening for attack information......");

byte[] bb = new byte[100];
int k = stm.Read(bb, 0, 100);
string atk = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bb.AsSpan(0, k));
```

Thank you.

// Code after help

```
private void Connectnattk_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            {

                {
                    try
                    {
                        IPAddress ipAd = IPAddress.Parse(IPV4.Text); //use local m/c IP address, and use the same in the client

                        /* Initializes the Listener */
                        TcpListener myList = new TcpListener(ipAd, 8001);

                        /* Start Listeneting at the specified port */
                        myList.Start();

                        MessageBox.Show("The server is running at port 8001...");
                        MessageBox.Show("The local End point is  :" + myList.LocalEndpoint);
                        MessageBox.Show("Looking for other computer");

                        Socket s = myList.AcceptSocket();
                        Console.WriteLine("Found buddy " + s.RemoteEndPoint);

                        ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
                        s.Send(asen.GetBytes(satt.Text));
                        MessageBox.Show("The command " + satt.Text + " was sent to the computer with IP address " + IPV4.Text);

                        byte[] b = new byte[100];
                        int k = s.Receive(b);
                        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
                            Console.Write(Convert.ToChar(b[i]));

                        void ServerStart()
                        {

                            TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 8001);

                            listener.Start();
                            Console.WriteLine("Listening on port: 8001");

                            while (true)
                            {
                                TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();

                                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state => HandleConnection(client));
                            }
                        }

                    void HandleConnection(TcpClient client)
                        {
                            Socket s = myList.AcceptSocket();
                            Console.WriteLine("Found buddy " + s.RemoteEndPoint);

                            ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
                            s.Send(asen.GetBytes(satt.Text));

                            Console.WriteLine("Number of connected buddies: " + connectedbuddies++);

                            client.Close();
                        }


                        /* clean up */

                        s.Close();
                        myList.Stop();

                    }
```

Comment: note that when you do a TCP receive you must loop till you receive all the data. This also means you have to know how big the message is going to be

Comment: One character / letter.

Comment: your client code says 100 in the receive, are you saying you are only sending one byte messages?

Answer (score 1):

Accepting a client socket in your code is synchronous, so you can only accept one client, process it then loop around to accept and process another.

You can use threads to add parallelism to your code. You create a method for handling client sockets and create a new thread for the client socket. This will allow you to continue looping to accept new incoming client socket connections whilst processing existing client socket connections.

```
static void ServerStart()
{
    TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 4480);

    listener.Start();
    Console.WriteLine("Listening on port: 4480");

    while (true)
    {
        // Accept the client connection before creating the thread.
        TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();

        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state => HandleConnection(client));
    }
}

static void HandleConnection(TcpClient client)
{
    // Insert your code here. (Do not accept socket again here)
    client.Close();
}
```

I create a new thread to run the `HandleConnection` method for each `TcpClient` using `ThreadPool`. You can create threads without ThreadPool however if threads are short-lived for performance reasons, you will want to use ThreadPool to create them.

Comment: Hi, please see the "code after help" section. That worked, both computers say the sucessfuly connected to the server, but the server still only sends the message to one of the listening computers, meaning the HandleConnection does not execute? Thanks.

Comment: @Theoneguy You are accepting the socket twice, that is why it is blocking. You should only accept the socket once before you create the thread.

You can either use `TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();` which is what I suggest as you are already using `TcpListener` or you should replace that line with `Socket s = myList.AcceptSocket();`.

I will update my answer to add more clarity.

Comment: Is there a way to run that code when the client connects? Thanks.

Comment: @Theoneguy You can't really do that. You wouldn't know how many threads you would need and therefore would either spawn too many or not enough to handle the connections. You might want to check out the asynchronous methods, there are already questions about them accepting multiple clients and it being non-blocking but you would have to learn asynchronous programming. If you want to work with the `Socket` object, just change the argument to the `HandleConnection` function but accept it before creating that thread.

Comment: What about using a foreach method? So, for each client connecting, send the message? Would that work?

Comment: @Theoneguy foreach is just a way of iterating over an enumerable type. Again, you wouldn't know how many incoming connections you could have. You just need to separate sending the message from accepting an incoming connection.

Comment: Right, and my thoughts on that are just to send the message to every client that does connect. Is there a way to do that with this code?